# run an application which windows task manager cannot show it?

Tags: windows, task-manager

Is it possible to run an application in Windows in such a way that window task manager cannot show it?

(It is running and it is usage from CPU and memory?)

Comment: You might want to add why you would want this. People sometimes come up with alternate solutions to the original problem.

Comment: No;  This is not possible.  All processes are displayed in the task manager.  If something is a service it would also be listed in the same location as all other services.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Technically no. It is possible for an application to run without a window handler, which means it will not show up in the application tab, but if you switch to the processes tab, you will still see it. More modern taskmanagers, such as ProcessHacker2 will show everything regardless how well someone tries to hide it.

Third option is if an application runs as service. It doesn't show up as process but rather as service.

Answer (score -1):

no, it's not possible.

The Task Manager is designed with numerous sections, with each of them performing an individual action of their own.

As LPChip said," if you run it without a window handler it will not show up in the application tab, but if you switch to the processes tab, you will still see it."

it means that if you hide it from one tab(category), then it will fall into other tab(category). there is no way that you can acheieve this. you can learn more about [windows task manger](https://windowsmaximizer.com/blog/task-manager/) here, and its working.